# Custom listbox, written in JS

Tags: javascript, html, listbox

Is there custom listbox written in JS? I need to be able to track what user selected before they actually select it, which I am not able to do using standart HTML select.

Is there custom listbox I can use instead?

**UPDATE:** Made it work by customizing Chosen jQuery plugin. Not the smoothest component I've dealt with, but works ok for me.

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to achieve?

Comment: Yep. I'd like to load preview image when user put mouse over the list item. Unfortunatelly I can't do it, when using standart HTML select — there is no way to know "where is user", before they actually select the item(

Comment: You can try and customize Chosen (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to your needs.

Comment: You can probably use getElementFromPoint in the select's mousemove to get the option element, E.g w/ jQuery `$("#listbox").mousemove(function(event) {  console.log( $(document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY)).text() )
});`

Comment: Doesn't work that way: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ8zt/

Comment: Oh I assumed it was in "listbox mode" i.e. with <select size=X (even then .hover would be better but that does not work for a dropdown select either)

Comment: Actually the best solution was to customize Chosen. Unfortunatelly it's buggy and doesn't support an event I need out of the box, but it's still the best solution at the moment.

Alex. K — thanks for suggestions about making standart component work as desired!